# Spring MVC - upload file is blocked by spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-security

I'm trying upload file. It works for me, but if I want to use uploading file it doesn't work. I'm getting this error

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

But if I comment these rows in web.xml it works:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I tried to add this config, but it didn't help

```
    <filter>
    <display-name>springMultipartFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my all web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
        <filter>
        <display-name>springMultipartFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Do you have any idea where could be a problem? I'm using these versions of spring and spring security:

```
<org.springframework.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<org.springframework.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadOneFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                logger.info("Server File Location="
                        + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

                return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name
                    + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }

}
```

JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload File Request Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="uploadOneFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> <br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Spring security-config

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/admin/goods" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password, enabled from admin where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: you need to show us your JSP/HTML page code where you generate form that will be used to submit the file.

Comment: also you need to paste in your controller code so we can see how its processed

Comment: I updated my question (jsp, controller and security config was added)

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem. I solved it from @user1604064.
You save my life

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I resolved this problem, I added  **?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}**  to end of my form action

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadOneFile?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now it works!

Comment: Why there are these asterisks? It worked for me only when I removed them.

Answer (score -1):

Change the following

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadOneFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to following

```
<form method="POST" action="/uploadOneFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Let me know if that works, if it doesn't then i'll suggest another thing.

Comment: It doesn't help. My application run on
`http://localhost:8080/spring-hibernate4/`
so when I set
<form method="POST" action="/uploadOneFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
I'm forwarded to `http://localhost:8080/uploadOneFile`
I tried to set
<form method="POST" action="/spring-hibernate4/uploadOneFile" enctype="multipart/form-data"> but I'm getting the same error HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported