# How to configure Spring Boot that it permits Wicket's file upload?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, spring-security, wicket

I use Spring Boot and Apache Wicket in a web application. I have to add file upload.

In the below code Wicket's Form component's onSubmit method is fired but "uploads" is empty.

```
@Override
            protected void onSubmit()
            {
                final List<FileUpload> uploads = fileUploadField.getFileUploads();

                if (uploads != null)
                {
                    for (FileUpload upload : uploads)
                    {
                        // Create a new file
                        File newFile = new File(getUploadFolder(), upload.getClientFileName());

                        // Check new file, delete if it already existed
                        checkFileExists(newFile);
                        try
                        {
                            // Save to new file
                            newFile.createNewFile();
                            upload.writeTo(newFile);

//                          UploadPage.this.info("saved file: " + upload.getClientFileName());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to write file", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Spring's configure method

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    }
```

I have created a separate application which contains Wicket but not Spring and same upload code works without problem.

I have tried this and did not work.

```
public class SecurityApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

         @Override
         protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
          insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter()); 
         }
    } 

    @Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")
     public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
          CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
          return multipartResolver;
     }
```

and when i add below suggestion to Form component's action url via javascript, Wicket's "onSubmit" method is not even triggered

[Spring MVC - upload file is blocked by spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612984/spring-mvc-upload-file-is-blocked-by-spring-security)

Edit:
When I watch on the network I see that Spring returns 302 to Wicket's POST request for upload.

Comment: Which versions of Spring Boot and Security do you use ?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0.2, Spring Security 5.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to application.properties file solved the problem.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran into this today while maintaining an old codebase. Saved my day!